# Importing CiviCRM Transactions into quickbooks

Tags: civireport

I'm wondering whether to start invoicing with Quickbooks and I am wondering if when I upload civicrm transactions into quickbooks if it will automatically link the payment to the invoice?

Can CiviCRM and Quickbooks to work together to avoid double entry?

Answer (score 3):

How about invoicing in CiviCRM - you can do so as of 4.6!

Here's how: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/contributions/invoicing/

Comment: I noticed that I can create an invoice by creating a contribution in "pending" status. I don't see how to update add a payment against this invoice though unless it is the full amount. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you enabled "Tax and Invoicing"?

Answer (score 1):

So after searching the web like a mad man for some instructions on integration with Quickbooks, I found very little.
I poked around for a while and this is what I found. Most of you probably know this already but for those who don't, this will be helpful.

To import transactions into quickbooks, you have to use Accounting batches in Contributions > Accounting Batches. Figuring out how to create batches is pretty straight forward. Then you want to export the batch as a .IIF file.

In Quickbooks From the File menu, choose Utilities , select Import and click IIF Files.

Quickbooks will import the transactions and its details as a General Journal. So if you were hoping (like I was) that it would create contacts quickbooks and fill the transactional data for each contact, it doesn't.

So my idea of invoicing from Quickbooks and having CiviCRM contributions credit the invoices doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but saw the recent blog post about the [CiviQuickbooks extension](https://github.com/agileware/au.com.agileware.civiquickbooks) which could be worth exploring.

- [QuickBooks Online integration with CiviCRM now available!](https://civicrm.org/blog/justinfreeman/quickbooks-online-integration-civicrm-now-available)

> If your organisation is using QuickBooks Online, then cheer up, we have some good news! You can now integrate your accounting system with CiviCRM:
>
> - CiviCRM Contacts and Contributions are pushed to QuickBooks
> - Linked QuickBooks Invoices are pulled into CiviCRM, updating the Contribution status.
> - Sit back and enjoy the synchronisation of all things!
>
> Integration of the two systems saves you time by not having to do repetitive data entry in your accounting system and CiviCRM. This extension does the work for you!